# Rails Devise Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Rails with the [Devise gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise).

If I try to sign-in with http://localhost:5000/users/sign_in

I get:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"users/home"}
```

Comment: devise_for :users,    :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On advice from the Advise team, I changed all of the links in my menu to named helpers and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems so that you are missing the devise routes. have enabled them in your routes.rb file?

there should be something like => devise_for :users

Comment: devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" }

Comment: I get this in the log:
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"devise/home"}):
12:05:37 web.1     |     47:           <div class="container nav-collapse">
12:05:37 web.1     |     48: 
12:05:37 web.1     |     49:   <ul class="nav pills">
12:05:37 web.1     |     50:             <li class="<%= "active" if params[:controller] == "home" %>"><%= link_to "Home", :controller => "home"  %></li>

Comment: I'm almost certain, that this is wrong... controller=>"devise/home"

Comment: I don't know where the controller=>"devise/home" is coming from.  I'm just going to this url= http://localhost:5000/users/sign_in

Comment: something is messed up with your routs. I would start out with cutting out possible error sources. Use the devise registrations controller first to see if it's basically working or not. alter your routes.rb file and remove your custom registrations controller path. simply use `devise_for :users` and go from there

Comment: I changed the routes.rb to just `devise_for :users`.
If I try to register using `http://localhost:5000/users/sign_up`
I get this error - again - `No route matches {:controller=>"devise/home"}`